# calling specific post with shortcode in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am building a wordpress with custom template, I created a page to display my home page with only specific post, however when I tried to call a post with a short code it won't show.

```
div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <?php
                        $post_id = 168;
                        $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
                        ?>
                            <?php echo $queried_post->post_content; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

thanks in advance, This is my first time creating a site using wordpress and I am not familiar with php at all.

Comment: Hi I already resolve the issue.

I replace the echo part with this code:

echo apply_filters('the_content',$queried_post->post_content);

thanks

Comment: Hi already resolve my issue